# Adding Selendroid to Android Studio gives error

Tags: java, android, selendroid

I am trying to add Selendroid to my android application so that I can scrape dynamic web content. So, I added the Selendroid Standalone Jar from [here](http://selendroid.io/setup.html), and then the client Jar from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/selendroid/selendroid-client/0.10.0/). Now, when I run my project, the Gradle build seems to take much longer than usual, and I am met with a multitude of messages (a part of which is shown below):

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.indexListFromLabelList(SsaMethod.java:157)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.newFromRop(SsaBasicBlock.java:164)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.convertRopToSsaBlocks(SsaMethod.java:173)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.newFromRopMethod(SsaMethod.java:103)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:44)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:297)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command  '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''   
finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

I have tried a ton of the solutions posted on this site which list similar errors, but nothing seems to work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to increase heap size.

Answer (score 1):

Increase heap size in gradle.build file

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}
```

It will take longer to build but it should work. You can also turn on gradle demon to increase build speed.